# How to delete or replace an already created symbolic link?

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation

I am working on my project using network simulator2. I installed it and everything is fine. I attempted to create a symbolic link between this installation and `/usr/bin`, so I could invoke the software by running `ns` from the command-line. Namely, I ran:

`sudo ln -s /home/vinaychalluru/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/ns /usr/bin/ns`

which generated the following output:

`ln: creating symbolic link '/usr/bin/ns': File exists`

---

**How can I delete the already created symlink or can I replace it with any other commands?**

Comment: I was trying to do `sudo ln -s destination source`, and of course it bugged. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
sudo rm -r /usr/bin/ns

sudo ln -s /home/vinaychalluru/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/ns /usr/bin/ns
```

Comment: the above fails if ns is a folder - in which case use the rm -rf (recursive force switches) - in which case you might as well use the -sf switches for ln.

Comment: @finley Yes, you are right. Incase *ns* is a folder, it can't be deletd. It is now ambiguos to me that, can we create a symbolic link to a folder.?

Comment: yes, we can create a symbolic link to a folder. If it's a folder, you can do: sudo rm -r /usr/bin/ns

Comment: @Pawel I created a symlink to folder succesfully. I can even remove as u said above. But, when i type *fold* [created symlink for a folder] name in terminal it gives an error. What i actually thought was by creating a symlink to a folder and just typing the link name terminal would open that in nautilus. I am not sure whether it is possible or not..?

Comment: @Vinaychalluru if you want to open that folder, try typing: cd fold - it will open in a terminal. If you want to open it in nautilus, type: nautilus fold

Comment: I did `sudo ln -s /home/vinayc/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/ /usr/bin/fol` >> `cd fol` which gave me an error `bash: cd: fol: No such file or directory`. It's because there is no folder *fol* in */home/vinayc/*. ? You said that, we can create a symbolic link to a folder. Should I make changes in the command.?

Comment: @Vinaychalluru no, that is not the point :) `sudo ln -s /home/vinayc/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/ /usr/bin/fol` and then `cd fol` or `nautilus fol`. These are 3 separate commands!

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding this method.  Misusing "rm -rf" with an ill-formatted input could be catastrophic.  Prefer "ln -sf" instead

Answer (score 76):

`ln` has `-f` switch that 'forces' a symlink to be created whether it exists or not.

```
sudo ln -sf /home/vinaychalluru/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/ns /usr/bin/ns
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: For some reason.... this does not work on my ubuntu 18.04 ... it does not complain, but it does not overwrite the existing link

Answer (score 29):

I tried `ln -sf` while replacing but it didn't work for me, but doing `ln -sfn directory link_name`  as `root` worked.

Comment: Without `-n` I was getting an infinite loop problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To add to all answers above, a symbolic link can be treated as a regular file in many cases (the link, not the target).

`rm` on a symbolic link will remove it. If the link is owned by root, you will need to sudo.

You should be able to `rm /usr/bin/ns` or rather `sudo rm /usr/bin/ns` don't forget ownership.